# Async and await functions running before others

Tags: javascript, async-await

My `proccess` await function don't wait for the end of `preProccess`:

I have a route class who call the controller

```
exports.Controller = async function (req, res) {

let callbackPreProccess = await Implementation.preProccess(payload, resolve);

let callbackProccess = await Implementation.proccess(callbackPreProccess, resolve);
res.status(200).json(callbackProccess);

//

export class Implementation{

    preProccess(payload: any, resolve: string): Promise<any> {
        return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
            try {
               if (payload.test == true){
                    logger.info('preProccess OK');
               }

               //preProccess connect to the DB and get some informations,
               //enrich the payload and return
               logger.info('preProccess DB access OK');

               resolve(payload);

           }
           catch(error){
               throw new Error("Manual Error");
               reject(error);
           }
    };


    proccess(payload: any, resolve: string): Promise<any> {
        return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
            try {
                logger.info('proccess OK');

                resolve(true);
            }
            catch(error){
                reject(error);
            }
    };
}
```

How are all await functions what I expect is:

```
info&& 'preProccess OK'
info&& 'preProccess DB access OK'
info&& 'proccess OK'
```

But return to me:

```
info&& 'preProccess OK'
info&& 'proccess OK'
info&& 'preProccess DB access OK'
```

Even when I force the throw error, expecting don't run the proccess, they run

```
info&& 'preProccess OK'
info&& 'proccess OK'
error&& 'Manual error'
```

But when I use a `.then` on `proccess` controller, waiting manually for the `preProccess`, it work very well.

Comment: Should you not define this: `preProccess` as `async preProccess`?

Comment: show your db connect code

Comment: @NegiRox 

//preProccess connect to the DB and get some informations;
In this case, I'm connect to another microService to do a get on the DB

Comment: **Like this:** 'await genericService.sendGet(reqGet, function (exception, request, response, callback) {}'

Answer (score 1):

use await while creating the new process.

```
 return await new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
```

Comment: [ts]
Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Promise<any>'.
  Property '[Symbol.toStringTag]' is missing in type '{}'.
[ts] 'await' expression is only allowed within an async function.'